# How to access token's data in dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, token

I have web api application .net framework 4.6.2 and we store user credentials in the token. I override dbcontext.savechanges to track database changes. I want to access userId which is stored in token and in api I can access that by httpContext. But the HTTP context is not available in dbcontext.

Answer (score 1):

Does `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` get the current Request Context?

I should point out that adding stuff that references this directly into a `DbContext` is poor design though...  You should probably use Dependency Injection and manage this via some service with a lifetime scoped to the request - or at least that's how I'd do it...

Comment: Do you have any sample for injecting that to dbcontext, I found some but all are using Identity. Can I inject token to db context? The issue is token is not ready when the dbcontext initialized it will become ready after user login.

Answer (score 1):

As @GPW said that's a poor design decision.
To solve that situation you need to use IoC to do registrations such as:

```
// Autofac
builder.Register(c => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
            .As<HttpContextBase>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

// Again Autofac 
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
```

```
// Castle Windsor
container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase()
                  .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
                  .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

With controllers using contructor injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public HomeController(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }
}
```

So you inject `HttpContextBase` in order to access the context

```
public class EntitiesContext : DbContext
{

    private readonly HttpContextBase _httpContext;

    public EntitiesContext(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Then how can I access httpcontext in dbcontext?

Comment: @rezord you just need to inject it on your DbContext class via constructor injection

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @rezord you welcome. can you please mark answer as valid and up-vote.